# Why can't I find gnomad2 in the repositories?

Tags: 10.10, repository

I've tried and tried, but I just can't seem to find gnomad2 ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=93810 ) in the Ubuntu repositories. I've already enabled all the "categories" in Software Sources (except Source Code), and I've "reloaded" (`apt-get update`) the repositories several times already. I feel like I'm doing something really stupid though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [removed from Debian](http://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gnomad2/news/20100623T100721Z.html) (and subsequently Ubuntu) for the following reasons:

> ROM; buggy, obsolete, abandoned upstream

A glance at the [project's home page](http://gnomad2.sourceforge.net/) doesn't really show any activity since 2008. Perhaps it might be useful to ask a question on how to get your specific hardware to work, maybe some other tool has the support you need.

Comment: Thanks. One thing though... What does "ROM" stand for? It seems like "Reason of Removal"...

Comment: No clue what that means, I'll ask around and update my question.